# How to measure Class Coupling metric with SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-analysis, metrics

I have the 7.0.0.36138 SonarQube version.

I’m trying to find a way to measure the Class Coupling metric of a project with SonarQube. In other versions of SonarQube it was possible to do it.

In this version, I tried to look over all the possible measures of my project, but I couldn’t find the Class Coupling.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your SonarQube to the [latest version](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/). We recently reimplemented [S1200](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1200) and it is available again. Please, not that SonarQube does not have class coupling metric built-in, just this rule will raise warnings if the coupling is above the specified threshold.

This rule was [dropped a few years ago](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-464) because its implementation generated too many false positives.